# Sair do laço assim que a string nome for igual a 0

Tags: c, c++, string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");

   int idade[20];
   string nome[20];
   char sexo[20],expe[20];

    for (int i=0; i <3; i++){

        do{
            cout << "digite o seu " << i+1 <<"º nome, idade, sexo e se tem experiência no serviço: ";
            cin >> nome[i];
            cin >> idade[i];
            cin >> sexo[i];
            cin >> expe[i];

        }while (strcmp(nome, ab)); /* está linha é que está com problema*/

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "está linha é que está com problema" -> qual problema? Isto é, que erro ocorre? P.S.: não seria a variável `ab`, que não está definida em lugar algum?

Comment: Tem alguns problemas, o primeiro é que isto não parece ter objetivo algum. Porque precisa fazer isto? Explique o objetivo, a lógica toda deve estar errada. E já lhe falei para não misturar C com C++.

Comment: é que eu não sei direto o que é C e o que é C++. A lógica é sair do laço assim que que a variável "nome" receba o valor 0.

Comment: Comece estudar essas coisas. Sair atirando para todo lado, sem um objetivo, sem um caminho traçado, não vai te levar a lugar algum. Você vai se iludir achando que está aprendendo alguma coisa e estará só seguindo fórmulas que não servirão pra nada na prática. O que você está querendo fazer não faz sentido, o problema está aí. Mas se insiste eu vou arrumar a sintaxe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "portuguese");
    int idade[20];
    string nome[20];
    char sexo[20], expe[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        do {
            cout << endl << "digite o seu " << i + 1 << "º nome, idade, sexo e se tem experiência no serviço: ";
            cin >> nome[i];
            cin >> idade[i];
            cin >> sexo[i];
            cin >> expe[i];
        } while (nome[i] == "0");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Ou5Jxl). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vhwmtkfd-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/ExitLoop.cpp).

Algumas coisas podem ser melhoradas. Idealmente seria melhor usar os recursos do C++ e evitar os do C.

Comment: Posso estar enganado, mas eu acho que ele só quer popular de informações nesse array. Seria um único FOR usando o tamanho do array. Esse "0" que ele citou deve ser do índice do array, que para ele 0 é o último.